# Delays in a continuous space

Tags: javascript, delay, anylogic

I have a population of agents moving randomly between nodes  in a continuous space
how can I let an agent enter a delay as it arrives at a node (assign a specific delay to each node ) then after the delay timeout an agent returns to its movement
is there a function that describes a waiting time in a certain location

I've tried enter.take command but since I have a population of agents and multiple enters an error pop up "Agent can't be in several flowcharts at the time"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "on agent arrival" transition type in your statechart. Make your agent `moveTo` a node with a state (see example models and tutorials, there are several that apply this concept).

In the state after the "on agent arrival" transition, you have another transition of type "Timeout" and give it the duration you want.

NOTE: Do not try to "sync" an agent state chart with a flow chart, you are destined for problems